# Workbook_BeforeClose across Application

Tags: excel, vba

I have `Workbook_BeforeClose` in '`This Workbook`' of my addin, and when I open several workbooks in the same excel instance and try to close each one of them, `Workbook_BeforeClose` does not get called for each such workbook open in the instance but only for the final workbbook.

Is there anyway of making `Workbook_BeforeClose` called for all the workbooks in an excel instance, where I need to perform tasks at each work book close?

Comment: if you want `Workbook_BeforeClose` to work on several workbooks then it needs to be implemented in each of those workbooks. Can you add the code to each of the workbooks? You could base each of the workbooks on a template that has the implementation in it and then take copies of the template. Or you could have a control `xlsm` file that is opening and closing various files and carrying out tasks on each book before it closes them - no need to use that event procedure then.

Comment: I m implementing an addin for excel, and currently I have caught Workbook_BeforeClose in 'This Workbook'. How to add this to each of the workbooks programatically? Can you provide any vba code sample?

Comment: the other option is to control all these events from Application point of view. It will require `Class module`. [Link to additional information about event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff836770%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks for the info and i m really interested on the 3 rd option you mentioned. Can you please provide code sample to show where am I to add this?

Comment: An addin that captures the closing of any workbook is the cleanest way to do this. It looks a lot like kazJaw's answer but includes an auto_open() event that initializes the event handler, and is saved as an addin that is loaded whenever you start excel. It will then work all the time.  If that is what you want, and you still need help, let me know and I will create the example.

Comment: @Floris I get the feeling this isn't a case where he wants it "always on" but more a situation where he needs to create an instance of excel and then load the addin. Although the application level code needn't necessarily be in a xlam file - could just be in a xlsm file that is opened in that instance of xl...like you say it's just a case of having an `auto_open` sub to get the ball rolling.

Comment: @whytheq you are probably right - which is why OP chose kazjaw's answer.

Comment: @Floris I just wanted to add a little more to this Q/A/Comments ...not really interested in what got chosen. Thanks for sorting out the code I was using.

Comment: +1 for the question - interesting topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few steps to follow.

1. create Class Module in your Excel IDE/VBA environment. Do it in one of the workbook which will be kept open until the end.
2. change Class Module name into `AppClass`
3. put this code inside `AppClass module`:

   ```
   Public WithEvents EXL As Application
   Private Sub EXL_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
       'sample msgbox
       MsgBox "You are about to close Workbook: " & Wb.Name
       'here your code
   End Sub
   ```
4. In any standard module, like `Module1`, insert the following code:

   ```
   Public appEXL As New AppClass
   Sub Required_Initialization()
       'run it once or run it when this workbook is opened
       Set appEXL.EXL = Application
   End Sub
   ```
5. Run the sub created in 4th step
6. Do some tests: a) create new empty workbook and next try to close it. You will get MsgBox calling the name of the workbook you are about to close.
7. Adjust as you need.

Important! Class are rather more difficult part of VBA programming. For better understanding try to search for any additional information in the web.

Comment: +1 great answer. As floris has pointed out replacing `Required_Initialization()` with `auto_open()` is a nice idea

Answer (score 0):

KazJaw's answer is a great idea.

I have an application-scoped addin using the technique he has outlined that has the following code in it:

```
Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Excel.Workbook)

    On Error GoTo NoBookOpen:
        If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual And LCase(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 6)) <> "export" Then
            If MsgBox("Calculation is set to Manual!" & vbCrLf & _
            "It will now be put back to Automatic", vbYesNo, "CALCULATION") = vbYes Then
                  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            End If
        End If
NoBookOpen:

End Sub
```

This addin is present in all my instances of Excel but you could use Kazjaw's idea and only load the add-in into specific instances of Excel.

Comment: @Floris lol - very true!!; I've had it running for about 3yrs and not looked at it for ages - yesterday copied it here and I was thinking that it seemed strange that the first half of the procedure had never messaged me!...I'll edit. The second section of the sub helps me regularly.

Comment: @Floris `VBA` is one thing but `SQL` is much worse for the "fresh set of eyes" thing!